Unable to set column width dynamatically in PrimeReact data-table
I have created SPFx with React solution. I have used "primereact": "^9.4.0" version.
I need to set the column width dynamically in the Prime React data-table column.
I have added the same code as below to bind dynamic columns in the Prime React data-table.
columnsArray?.map((col) => {
  return (
    <Column
    key={col?.field}
    field={col?.field}
    header={col?.header} 
    style={{ width: col?.width + 'px', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}
    sortable
    filter
    filterClear={filterClearTemplate}
    filterApply={filterApplyTemplate}
    reorderable={true}
    body={getAllFieldData}
   />
  )
 }
})

Everything is working as expected except the width property.
Also, I have tried max-width and min-width properties, and it works as expected.
Can anyone help me with the same?
Thanks

I am having the same issue.

Is there any update?
